# How to change the color of a selected feature with pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, color

is it possible to change the color of a selected feature in qgis 1.8?
To highlight a feature I use:

```
vlayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectedList)
box = vlayer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

But the selected featue is colored yellow. Is it possible to define for example a red color for this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, if you use QGIS >= v.2.4, you can set the selection color from the QGIS Python console in this way:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor( QColor("red") )
```