# Setting the alpha channel value of the colour of selected features using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5

I want to be able to set the value of the alpha channel of the selected features' colors in order to see what's under those features.

This thread gives a good answer to set the color of the selected features using [PyQGIS](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.26/):
[How to change the color of a selected feature with pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72436/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-selected-feature-with-pyqgis)

For example, this command will switch color of selected features from yellow (default) to red:

```
>>> iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor( QColor("red") )
```

[image]  →  [image]

But how to set up an alpha value if you want to see what's under (e.g. the base map) your selected features ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.fromRgb()` method of the `QColor` object, e.g.:

```
>>> iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor( QColor().fromRgb(255,0,0,255) )
```

Obviously, this will give the same as the red color above but if you set a lower value for alpha, you will then see underlying object, here some buildings and paths on a base map:

```
>>> iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor( QColor().fromRgb(255,0,0,128) )
```

[image]

Or for a fully transparent selection:

```
>>> iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor( QColor().fromRgb(255,0,0,0) )
```

[image]

#### Doc:

PyQt5 `QColor` object: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QColor.html

`fromRgb()` method: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QColor.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QColor.fromRgb

but this is not 100% clear to me because it states :

> The alpha component of rgb is ignored (i.e. it is automatically set to
> 255), use the fromRgba() function to include the alpha-channel
> specified by the given QRgb value.

and the signature gives: `def fromRgb (r, g, b[, a=255])` which I successfully tested above.

The [`fromRgba()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QColor.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QColor.fromRgba) method accept an integer only which you may figure out how to build. For example, you can see this corresponding `int` value using `.rgba()` on the `QColor` object:

```
>>> QColor().fromRgb(255,0,0,64).rgba()
1090453504
```

This is my version info:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(f"Python version: {sys.version}")
Python version: 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0]

>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR
>>> print(f"Qt: {QT_VERSION_STR}\nPyQt: {PYQT_VERSION_STR}")
Qt: 5.15.3
PyQt: 5.15.6
```

Tested on [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) 3.26.2-Buenos Aires.